# Would file system caching using the same amount of storage space as memory caching?

Tags: php, memcached, phpfastcache

I'm thinking of replacing some of my file system caching (via phpfastcache) over to memcache (again using phpfastcache) but I have a query on storage sizes. Potentially a silly question but:

If I had 80gb of file cache storage being used would that equal to needing 80gb of ram to store the exact same cache via memory?

I'm thinking they potentially use different compression methods but I've struggled to find an answer online.

Answer (score 0):

80gb of cache is huge, I'm myself surprised that Phpfastcache handles it well. If you migrate to Memcache, for sure you can expect some serious memory issue on the server.

For such size I recommend you more performant backends such as Mongodb/Couchdb/Arangodb or maybe Redis too.

If you're just looking for backend storage stats, you can have a look at this API offered by Phpfastcache: [Wiki - Cache Statistics](https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache/wiki/%5BV5%CB%96%5D-The-cache-statistics)
It will return you misc statistics provided by the backends supported by Phpfastcache.

*(Note: I'm the author of this Library)*